# How to access terminal history in node.js?

Tags: node.js, command-line, pipe, command-line-arguments

I like to process piped commands from within my Node.js commandline app like `myapp.babel app.es6 | mynodecmdlineapp`. To build a refresh mechanism I need to access the previous terminal commandline text. The place where terminal history is saved varies depending on the shell. Is there a node way to read this out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly answer, but, if you are constructing the entire chain of commands, you could construct it to also pass the first command that you execute as a first argument to mynodecmdlineapp.

You could then access argv in your mynodecmdlineapp. See,
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv

An example call would look like this:

```
myapp.babel app.es6 | mynodecmdlineapp "myapp.babel app.es6"
```

process.argv[2] would then contain "myapp.babel app.es6" but this assumes that you are constructing the command and able to call it this way. Otherwise, I thought you might be able to leverage "!!" to send the last command, but that would send the last command in history -- not in that command's pipe sequence.